# Move div works in Fiddle, but not in my page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Now, I have a little problem: when using fiddler. It works, but on my server it doesn't work and I don't understand why.

http://jsfiddle.net/5mvKE/501/

My page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <style>
  #test { 
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
       height: 70px;
       background-color: #d2fcd9;
  }
 </style>
<script src="/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script src="test.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
 <div id="test">test div</div>
</body>
</html>
```

For the script, I tried to put `<script>` into `<head>`, `<body>` and external (see above), but nothing works.

I used only `<!DOCTYPE html>` (compatible HTML 5) and also

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`
```

but this does not affect the result.

Comment: Did you put your jQuery code in a `$(document).ready()` call? http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/. Fiddles run in the `$(window).load()` by default (see the options in the upper left corner).

Comment: Also, why are you including two copies of jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which browser are you trying your code in ?

I think this one will work:

```
$div.css({
    left: Math.floor( Math.random() * widthMax )+"px",
    top: Math.floor( Math.random() * heightMax )+"px"
});
```

and write all your jquery code inside `$(document).ready(function(){//code});`

Comment: IE11, Chrome and FF. Thank you IVlajid. Indeed, when I replace .click with .ready, it works! :) Now, I have another question: I would like a infinity loop. I think this (but not works): function poz () { //jQuery code }); poz() };